# Proving Continuity in Higher Dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

In one dimension ($\mathbb{R}$), using epsilon-delta proofs is a very straightforward process. You start with $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ and you manipulate the inequality algebraically until you can obtain $|x-x_0| <$ [expression]. Then you let $\delta = $ [expression]. And doing the algebra in reverse gives the conclusion.

Now, in more than one dimension (i.e. when the ***codomain*** is multi-dimensional), it becomes less obvious how to use this same process to obtain a $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$. I show my work below.

*Proof Attempt*.

In order to show that $f$ is continuous, we show that

$$ \forall \, \varepsilon > 0, \exists \, \delta > 0  \, \forall \, j_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2, \|j - j_0 \| < \delta \implies \|f(j) - f(j_0) \| < \varepsilon$$

where $j_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and for fixed $j \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

So we start with  $\|f(j) - f(j_0)\| < \varepsilon$.

$$ \| (x^2-y^2, 2xy) - (x_0^2 - y_0^2, \, 2x_0y_0) \| < \varepsilon$$

$$\| (x^2-y^2 - ( x_0^2 - y_0^2), 2xy - 2x_0y_0 ) \| < \varepsilon$$

$$\sqrt{\Big[x^2-y^2 - ( x_0^2 - y_0^2) \Big]^2 + \Big[ 2xy - 2x_0y_0 \Big]^2} < \varepsilon$$

$$\Big[x^2-y^2 - ( x_0^2 - y_0^2) \Big]^2 + \Big[ 2xy - 2x_0y_0 \Big]^2 < \varepsilon^2$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\|(x-x_0, y- y_0) \| < \delta$$

---

Am I on the right track here? The `\vdots` are the remaining steps I need to obtain my $\delta$ but it doesn't appear to me that I can end up with $|(x-x_0 , y-y_0) | <$ [expression] without lumping variables over on the righthand side.

Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea will absolutely work! In general, to show that a function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous (where $X$ and $Y$ have notions of "[distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)", say $d_X$ and $d_Y$) we can always show that

$$\forall \epsilon . \exists \delta . d_X(x_1, x_2) < \delta \implies d_Y(f x_1, f x_2) < \epsilon.$$

For $\mathbb{R}^n$ the standard euclidean metric $d_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x_1, x_2) = \lVert x_1 - x_2 \rVert$ works, and we exactly recover your idea.

However, as you've noticed this feels *messy*. We have to work with a bunch of squares and square roots, and even working with the usual tricks (like trying to get $d(x_1,x_2)^2$ small instead) still leaves us wondering if there's an easier way. The answer, thankfully, is *yes*!

> **Theorem:**
> $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous if and only if each of the coordinate functions are continuous separately.

What does that mean concretely? Well $f = (f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m)$ where each $f_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. The theorem tells us that it's enough to check that each of these $f_i$ are continuous! In fact, this generalizes:

> **Theorem:** $f : X \to Y \times Z$ is continuous if and only if the functions $\pi_Y \circ f : X \to Y$ and $\pi_Z \circ c: X \to Z$ are continuous. (Here $\pi_Y (y,z) = y$ and $\pi_Z(y,z) = z$).

This turns out to be related to the [categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) notion of "product", but I won't go into that here.

> Exercise: Can you prove this theorem? At least in the case of $X = Y = \mathbb{R}^2$? You'll need to do an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument using the $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ distance.

Now how does this simplify your life in your concrete example? Well now we just want to show that

- $(x,y) \mapsto x^2 - y^2$
- $(x,y) \mapsto 2xy$

are continuous. But this should be easier. First of all, they're polynomials, so if you know that all polynomials are continuous you're done immediately. But even if you *don't* know that, it should be easier to use an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument to finish this up now that the codomain is one dimensional. If nothing else, that should be *much* cleaner now that you don't have to worry about square roots, etc.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Suppose I wanted to do this the "messy" way. Would it be sufficient to find a $\delta$ for the $x$ dimension and a $\delta$ for the $y$ dimension and then take the minimum of the two?

Comment: Yup! That's exactly how you prove the theorem, and so doing it directly for your particular function $f$ works just as well ^_^

Comment: Hey im late a bit. @HallaSurvivor how would you prove that for example $f(x,y)=x+y$ Is continuous? Do I first evaluate $f(x)=x +y$ where y is a constant and the same for $f(y)=x+y$ where in this case x is a constant.