# Continuation of Proving Continuity in Higher Dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In a previous post, [Proving Continuity in Higher Dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306478/proving-continuity-in-higher-dimensions), I asked about proving continuity in higher dimensions. I am focusing on the same problem but wish to provide an updated proof attempt in this post as I am still stuck.

**Exercise** Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

> For this problem, I will be using the 1-norm which is defined by: $x = \langle x_1, x_2\ \dots, x_n \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $\|x\|_1 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ (also called the Taxicab norm)

*Attempt.*

In order to show that $f$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, we show that

$$ \forall \, \varepsilon > 0, \exists \, \delta > 0  \, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \|x - x_0, y-y_0 \|_1 < \delta \implies \|f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \|_1 < \varepsilon$$

Consider $\|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)\|_1$

$$\|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)\|_1 = \| (x^2-y^2,2xy) - (x_0^2-y_0^2,2x_0y_0) \|_1$$

$$= \| (x^2-y^2-x_0^2+y_0^2, 2xy-2x_0y_0)  \|_1$$

$$= |x^2-y^2-x_0^2+y_0^2| + |2xy-2x_0y_0|$$

$$= |(x^2-x_0^2)+(y_0^2-y^2)| + |2xy - 2x_0y + 2x_0y + 2x_0y_0|$$

$$\leq |x^2-x_0^2| +|y^2-y_0^2| + |2y| |x-x_0| + |2x_0||y-y_0|$$

$$= |x+x_0||x-x_0| +|y+y_0||y-y_0| + |2y| |x-x_0| + |2x_0||y-y_0|$$

$$= |x-x_0+2x_0||x-x_0| +|y-y_0+2y_0||y-y_0| + |2y| |x-x_0| + |2x_0||y-y_0|$$

$$ \leq (|x-x_0|+|2x_0|)|x-x_0| +(|y-y_0| + |2y_0|)|y-y_0| + |2y| |x-x_0| + |2x_0||y-y_0|$$

$$ \leq (1^*+|2x_0|)|x-x_0| +(1 +|2y_0|)|y-y_0| + |2y| |x-x_0| + |2x_0||y-
y_0|$$

$$ \leq (1+|2x_0|)\delta +(1 +|2y_0|)\delta + |2y| \delta + |2x_0|\delta$$

$$= \delta (1+|2x_0| + (1+2|y_0|) + |2y| + |2x_0|)$$

$$= \delta (2 +|4x_0| + |2y_0|+|2y|)$$

$^*$ Note: I seek to eventually have $\delta = \min\{1, g(\varepsilon) \}$ where $g$ is some expression with $\varepsilon$ in it. It is this $g(\varepsilon)$ that I am struggling to obtain, not least because of the $|2y|$ hanging out in the expression.

Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with that pesky unfixed $|2y|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\delta > \|(x-x_0, y-y_0)\|_1 = |x-x_0| + |y-y_0| \geq |y-y_0| \geq |y| - |y_0|.$ Then, $|y| \leq \delta + |y_0|$.